# Core data fetch request to search in array

Tags: core-data, request, nsarray, fetch

I have an object in core data which contains an NSArray filed. This is an array of categories (just strings).

ANd i need to get all objects for certain category. So if an object has an array of categories "film", "music" and i need to get all the film objects - this object is what i need.

so how to write fetch request which wiil search for the value in some array field?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating another object in your model called `Category`. Create relationships between the two objects. Make both of them To-Many relationships.

In your `Category` object create a string attribute called `name`. This will be where you set it to `film`, `music`, etc. You should then be able to pull back all the objects that match the film category using a predicate such as this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY categories.name == %@", category];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please watch from [Standford Uni. CS193p Video Lectures](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225), the Core Data is explained greatly

Comment: While this is a useful resource, it is not very specific to the question at hand.